# Getting fields from a String separated by #

Tags: php, string

I have a string and I would want to get the values/fields from it. However, the values are `#` separated.

Also, from one copy to the next it is comma separated.

As shown below;

```
$transaction = "
[2018-01-10 12:50:07.822#SAMUEL#TITUS],
[20120605152613#KEN#NAUGH],
[20120705152645#JOHHY#BRAVO]";
```

I need to loop through this string getting the values separated by the `#` for one record the to the next record separated by a comma.

The order of the fields is `[TIME#FIRST_NAME#SECOND_NAME]`.

I can't think of a way to get this done.

Anyone?

Comment: You can use `explode()` to start with to split it by commas, then do the same with each field with '#'

Comment: [explode()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to parse string into array

```
<?php
$transaction = "[2018-01-10 12:50:07.822#SAMUEL#TITUS],[20120605152613#KEN#NAUGH],[20120705152645#JOHHY#BRAVO]";
$parsed = explode(",", $transaction);

foreach($parsed as $val){

    $val = explode("#", $val);
    $first_name = $val[1];
    $last_name = str_replace("]", '', $val[2]);

    echo $first_name." ".$last_name."<br>"; // get firstname & lastname 

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$transaction = "
    [2018-01-10 12:50:07.822#SAMUEL#TITUS],
    [20120605152613#KEN#NAUGH],
    [20120705152645#JOHHY#BRAVO]";

//normalize the string and remove the unnecessary chars.
$transaction = str_replace(['[', ']', "\n"], '', $transaction);

//get all the rows as array.
$rows = explode(',', $transaction);

//create the columns in rows.
$row_arr = array_map(function ($row) {
    return explode('#', $row);
}, $rows);

//info of the first row.
echo $row_arr[0][0]; // time
echo $row_arr[0][1]; // firstname
echo $row_arr[0][2]; // lastname

//run through the rows to output.
foreach ($row_arr as $row_item) {
    echo 'Time: '.$row_item[0].', Firstname: '.$row_item[1].', Lastname: '.$row_item[2]."<br>";
}
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/3uYcSw